# Execute SQL Task Editor

Tags: sql, ssis

There are 2 Option to use dynamic query in `Execute SQL Task`, Parameter Mapping and Expression.

`Variable` - where you create query on a variable e.g `"Select * from" +@User::TableName`
`Expression` - where you create query direct to expression, same sample above.

Questions is which of the 2 is mostly used or better to use since this 2 have the same output?

Comment: Execute SQL task, component in SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Execute SQL Task` for your case using variable or expression. There is nothing like which is better. It all depends on your requirement. Both of the options have its  pros and cons, so it is hard to predict which is better in your case without knowing your requirement.

You may check

- [Using SSIS Package Configuration Values as Parameters to Execute SQL
  Tasks](http://sqlship.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/using-ssis-package-configuration-values-as-parameters-to-execute-sql-tasks/)
- [Variables and Expressions in SSIS](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/KathiKellenberger/sql-server/3629/variables-and-expressions-in-ssis)